# partially computable function computed with propositional logic program

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, computability

Can all partially computable functions be computed with a propositional  logic program?

I think yes, but can some one tell me why?

Comment: What is a propositional logic program?

Comment: Assignment Language

Comment: OK, what's "Assignment Language"? (Are you talking about [logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming), like Prolog? If so, [it is indeed Turing-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/what-makes-prolog-turing-complete).) Please make the question self-contained.